# plot_slopes cannot compute predicted regression model values in an iterative function, but can predict each one outside of the function

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapply, marginal-effects, r-marginaleffects

This is a difficult question to answer as I cannot provide actual replication data (my apologies, the data is too large/sensitive) but I would appreciate anyone's ideas. I use sample data here to show the structure of the code, though this code will not produce the error I detail below.

I have a complicated function where I perform multiple regressions to isolate interaction effects and plot them together using the `plot_slopes` function from the wonderful `marginaleffects` package. My code is structured like the below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

outcome_var_list = c("mpg","cyl","hp")
interact_var_list =  c("am","wt")
subset_var_list = c("3","4")

combos = expand.grid(outcome_var_list, subset_var_list)


model_ <- function(k,c){

mtcars = mtcars[mtcars$gear == c,]

outcome_var_list = outcome_var_list[outcome_var_list == k] 

results = list()
  for (r in interact_var_list) {
    f = paste(k, "~", r, "*factor(vs)")
    m = lm(f, subset(mtcars, carb %in% c(1,2,3,4)))
    s = plot_slopes(m, variables = r, condition = "vs", draw = FALSE)
    tmp = s[, c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high", "vs")]
    tmp$outcome = k
    tmp$regressor = r
    results = c(results, list(tmp))
  }
results = do.call("rbind", results)  


plot1 = results %>% 
  mutate(min = min(conf.low), max = max(conf.high)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(vs), 
             y=estimate, 
             color = regressor, 
             ymin=conf.low, 
             ymax=conf.high)) + 
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.4)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.4)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  ggtitle(label = paste0("Model 1: ",k)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  labs(y= "Interaction Coefficient", x = "X") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_textbox_simple(vjust=-1)) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(2,0,0,0, "cm")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5))

  ggsave(plot1,file=paste0("plot_",k,".png"),path=paste0(c))

}


safe_model <- safely(model_)
iterate <-mapply(safe_model,combos$Var1,combos$Var2)
```

When I ran this before adding the extra `subset_var_list` everything was produced just fine.

However, when I added the subsetting var and switched to mapply, I now generate the model for entire subsets of the data where only a few `outcome_var`s can produce plots to save. I assumed this was due to a lack of coverage or something, so I removed `safely`, and this revealed the following error:

```
Error: Unable to compute predicted values with this model. You can try to supply a different dataset to the `newdata` argument.
  If this does not work, you can file a report on the Github Issue Tracker:
  https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues
```

I again assumed this was due to a lack of coverage/variation, so I tried running `plot_slopes` manually for each individual interaction regression instead of through the function, and every single plot/regression was successfully generates for one of the subsets that otherwise would not generate plots. So it does not appear to be an issue with the model/lack of variation.

I may misunderstand how the `newdata` argument proposed in the error message works, but it seems that it has the complete data to perform the task and that that should provide no advantage. Is there a reason why the regressions/slope models can be produced individually/manually, while when put together in this function they cannot be predicted? How can I fix this problem and create all the plots I need for every subset?

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to make it work, but I am still wondering what the issue is, and hopefully if there is a way to increase the speed of running the models.

I filtered the model within the for loop to remove NA's for the outcome variable. My rationale with this is that some interaction variables in my dataset do not have any data coverage, so perhaps when they are all NAs it triggers the message about insufficient factor levels, even though all NAs are removed in the regression, so they should be dropped. I do this manually in case before the regression, and it now works

My new code is the below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

outcome_var_list = c("mpg","cyl","hp")
interact_var_list =  c("am","wt")
subset_var_list = c("3","4")

combos = expand.grid(outcome_var_list, subset_var_list)


model_ <- function(k,c){

mtcars = mtcars[mtcars$gear == c,]

outcome_var_list = outcome_var_list[outcome_var_list == k] 

results = list()
  for (r in interact_var_list) {
    f = paste(k, "~", r, "*factor(vs)")
    m = lm(f, mtcars %>% filter(is.na(k))
    s = plot_slopes(m, variables = r, condition = "vs", draw = FALSE)
    tmp = s[, c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high", "vs")]
    tmp$outcome = k
    tmp$regressor = r
    results = c(results, list(tmp))
  }
results = do.call("rbind", results)  


plot1 = results %>% 
  mutate(min = min(conf.low), max = max(conf.high)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(vs), 
             y=estimate, 
             color = regressor, 
             ymin=conf.low, 
             ymax=conf.high)) + 
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.4)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.4)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  ggtitle(label = paste0("Model 1: ",k)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  labs(y= "Interaction Coefficient", x = "X") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_textbox_simple(vjust=-1)) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(2,0,0,0, "cm")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5))

  ggsave(plot1,file=paste0("plot_",k,".png"),path=paste0(c))

}


safe_model <- safely(model_)
iterate <-mapply(safe_model,combos$Var1,combos$Var2)
```

This runs the models and allows me to generate them successfully. However, when I try to filter the dataframe outside of the `results = list(...` loop to increase the speed of the processing, I still receive the original error:

```
Error: Unable to compute predicted values with this model. You can try to supply a different dataset to the `newdata`
  argument. If this does not work, you can file a report on the Github Issue Tracker:
  https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues
```

This is weird to me, because theoretically if the df is filtered at either stage, the results should be the same. Is there any reason for this error when filtering outside the for loop? And if it cannot be resolved, is there a way to speed up this process when filtering within the for loop?

Comment: In above sample code, variable `wt` is member both ot `outcome_var_list` and `interact_var_list`. Thus, there are iterations, where it is used simultaneously as outcome and predictor variable which throws an error.

Comment: @I_O Yes, I note this in the line immediately after the code chunk, this does not produce the error. For simplicities sake I will remove this however. But the issue must be something else.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, and this is one of the trickiest and hardest to debug corners of the package (ie: mining through model objects in nested environments to recover the training data). But if I were you, I would try to use `slopes()` directly instead of `plot_slopes()`. You can easily reporduce the same results by using something like: `slopes(model, newdata=datagrid(vs = seq(min(vs), max(vs), length.out = 100)))`

Comment: Thank you for the idea. In this case, oddly even fewer of the models can be generated @Vincent

Comment: I have updated the question with another attempt at solving it, this time with different errors.

Answer (score 1):

Using the tidyverse anyway, you could create a grid (`expand.grid`) with the desired combinations and extend this dataframe with a column to hold the models and another one to hold the plot objects for further use (saving them as a side-effect along the way).
*Note the use of `rowwise()` and `list()` to fit an arbitrary object into a dataframe cell*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

## subset mtcars once only (unless you want different subsets
## per row):
d <- subset(mtcars, carb %in% 1:4)

result <- 
  expand.grid(outcome = c('mpg','cyl','hp'),
              regressor = c('am', 'wt')
              ) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(model = list(
           lm(sprintf('%s ~ %s * factor(vs)', outcome, regressor), data = d)
         ),
         slopes = list(slopes(model)),
         plots = list({p <- ggplot(data = slopes) +
                    geom_point(aes(factor(vs), estimate, color = term))
                    ## save the plot as you go:
                    ggsave(p, filename = sprintf('plot_%s_%s.png', outcome, regressor))
                    p ## return the plot object
         })
         )
```

output:

```
## > result
## # A tibble: 6 x 5
## # Rowwise: 
##   outcome regressor model  slopes             plots 
##   <fct>   <fct>     <list> <list>             <list>
## 1 mpg     am        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>  
## 2 cyl     am        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>  
## 3 hp      am        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>  
## 4 mpg     wt        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>  
## 5 cyl     wt        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>
```

pick and re-use objects as needed, e. g.:

```
> result$model[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = sprintf("%s ~ %s * factor(vs)", outcome, regressor), 
    data = d)

Coefficients:
   (Intercept)              am     factor(vs)1  am:factor(vs)1  
        194.17          -50.42          -92.02           28.85
```

**edit**

To calculate per gear leavel, you can slightly modify above code (`nest_by` of {dplyr} would be another approach):

```
result <- 
  expand.grid(gear = 3:5, ## add gear to factor combinations
              outcome = c('mpg','cyl','hp'),
              regressor = c('am', 'wt')
              ) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(model = list(
           lm(sprintf('%s ~ %s * factor(vs)', outcome, regressor),
              ## subset by gear:
              data = subset(d, gear == gear)
              )
         ),
         slopes = list(slopes(model)),
         plots = list({p <- ggplot(data = slopes) +
                    geom_point(aes(factor(vs), estimate, color = term))
                    ## save the plot as you go:
                    ggsave(p, filename = sprintf('plot_%s_%s.png', outcome, regressor))
                    p ## return the plot object
         })
         )
```

output:

```
## # A tibble: 18 x 6
## # Rowwise: 
##     gear outcome regressor model  slopes             plots 
##    <int> <fct>   <fct>     <list> <list>             <list>
##  1     3 mpg     am        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>  
##  2     4 mpg     am        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>  
##  3     5 mpg     am        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>  
##  4     3 cyl     am        <lm>   <slopes [60 x 15]> <gg>  
## ... 14 more rows
```

Comment: you could also use `crossing()` or `expand()` if you want to go full tidyverse ...

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am not sure how this matches the model. The subsetting of the df that is important is the subsetting for values of ```gear```, as shown above. Is there a way to incorporate that in your suggestion?

Comment: Thanks, this is closer, and I can indeed generate plots for the variables that I once could not. But it still doesn't exactly match what I do in the first model. In your edit, the result are multiple plots for each regression. But I would like each regression plotted in the same plot. I would only like to model the interaction of the regressor  and vs, not get independent estimates for VS as in the current model. Is this possible. (I also appreciate the simplicity of the spintf addition, that's a nice touch!)

Comment: Now that you got a working template for how to iterate through an custom combination of inputs, feed an arbitrary payload of functions to the mill, harvest side-effects (such as plots) and store the results together with the input in a dataframe ... why not take it from there to tailor your solution? Should that fail, you can always single out the specific issue (which then will probably some detail *apart* from the iteration machinery) and post it as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?